# How can (1 +) be ever a function?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, and trying to understand the following codes (derived from an example in the Beginning Scala book)

```
scala> def w42(f: Int => Int) = f(42)  //(A)
w42: (f: Int => Int)Int

scala> w42 (1 +)      //(B)
res120: Int = 43
```

I do not understand how "1 +" at point (B) is consider as a function (take 1 Int parameter, and return an Int) that satisfies the w42 definition at point (A)?

Would you mind please explain or point me to some documents that have the answer?

Answer (score 11):

Simple. In Scala `1 + 2` is just a syntax sugar over `1.+(2)`. This means `Int` has a method named `+` that accepts `Int`:

```
final class Int extends AnyVal {
  def +(x: Int): Int = //...
  //...
}
```

This is why you can use `1 +` as if it was a function. Example with less unexpected method naming:

```
scala> def s42(f: String => String) = f("42")
s42: (f: String => String)String

scala> s42("abc".concat)
res0: String = abc42
```

BTW Technically speaking, *eta-expansion* is also involved to convert method to a function.

Comment: Maybe some useful hint: `1+` means `1+_` means `x=>1+x`

Comment: Thanks Tomasz for additional example.

Comment: Thanks Antoras for the useful hint